# how to use cefsharp emulation a mobile environment

Tags: mobile, emulation, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I used cefsharp65, i need to emulation a mobile environment for test.

In chrome i can use 'Toggle device toolbar' to choose a mobile environment. but cefsharp has no toolbar, is there any way to realize?

I used the follow code,but do nothing.

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--touch-devices", "enabled");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--touch-events", "enabled");
```

Comment: `CEF` doesn't support device emulation, see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1992/devtools-device-emulation-mode-missing-in

Comment: `touch-devices` is a linux command line argument see https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#touch-devices

Comment: For touch events try `settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("touch-events", "1");`. It might not be supported by `CEF`.